# Difference between exports and this

Tags: node.js, requirejs

I have seen in some modules they use `modules.exports.something = ()->` , or `exports.something = ()->`.

And at some other times is done with `this.something = ()->`.

Apparently resulting in the same behavior. Is one better than the other? Does `this` refer to the `exports` object or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exports` and `module.exports` typically exist in environments that provide some sort of module loading system. For instance Node.js uses the CommmonJS module system. RequireJS provides an AMD-style system. A web page loaded in a browser that does not additionally load some sort of module system (like RequieJS) won't have `exports` and `module.exports` defined. If you do have a module system at hand and want to export values, it is normally the case that you'd assign what you want to export to `exports` or `module.exports`, or fields on these objects.

What `this` refers to is highly dependent on context. If you create a file with only `console.log(this)` and run it with Node.js, you'll see `{}` output to the console. If you try the same in a blank HTML page loaded in Chrome, you'll see that `this` is the `window` object. So in a browser, assigning to `this.foo` in the outermost scope is equivalent to assigning to `window.foo` and is a way to declare `foo` in the global space.  What you'll sometimes see is code designed to work in various environments that will change the value of `this` depending on where it running. Something like:

```
function factory() {
    this.foo = function () {...};
    this.bar = "q";
}

if (typeof exports !== 'undefined')
    factory.call(exports); // CommonJS or AMD environment.
else if (typeof window !== 'undefined')
    factory.call(window); // Browser.
else
    factory.call(this); // Something else.
```

Using the `call` method on the `factory` function like above sets the value of `this` inside `factory` to the first parameter passed to `call`.